# How to Crop the visible portion of landscape video in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, video, ffmpeg, textureview

1. I am working on Panning and cropping the landscape video using Texture     View.I am in a half way that I can pan the landscape video from left to right vice versa by using this example
   https://github.com/crust87/Android-VideoCropView.

[image]

[image]

2. FFMPEG can crop the particular portion of the video by using this command
   `ffmpeg -i /sdcard/videokit/in.mp4 -filter:v crop=720:1088:0:0 -c:a
   copy /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4`

How can I crop only the video which is visible in Texture View and save it local storage in Android.

> crop=720:1088:0:0     is a hard coded width and height of the video and it is cropping fine.But how can I get the width and height of the visible video in Texture View to crop the visible video and Save it to the local storage in android.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Layout Components
    private FrameLayout top_frame;

    // Attributes
    private String originalPath;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.check);
        top_frame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.top_frame);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1000 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            final VideoCropView mVideoCropView = new VideoCropView(this);
            mVideoCropView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mVideoCropView.start();
                }
            });
            top_frame.addView(mVideoCropView);
            Uri selectedVideoUri = data.getData();

            originalPath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedVideoUri);

            mVideoCropView.setVideoURI(selectedVideoUri);

            mVideoCropView.seekTo(1);
        }
    }

    public void onButtonLoadClick(View v) {
        top_frame.removeAllViews();
        Intent lIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        lIntent.setType("video/*");
        lIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivityForResult(lIntent, 1000);
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {    // getting image path from gallery.
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

CropVideoView

```
public class VideoCropView extends TextureView implements MediaPlayerControl {
    // Constants
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "VideoCropView";
    private static final int STATE_ERROR = -1;
    private static final int STATE_IDLE = 0;
    private static final int STATE_PREPARING = 1;
    private static final int STATE_PREPARED = 2;
    private static final int STATE_PLAYING = 3;
    private static final int STATE_PAUSED = 4;
    private static final int STATE_PLAYBACK_COMPLETED = 5;

    // MediaPlayer Components
    protected Context mContext;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private Surface mSurface;
    private OnInfoListener mOnInfoListener;
    private OnCompletionListener mOCompletionListener;
    private OnErrorListener mOnErrorListener;
    private OnPreparedListener mOnPreparedListener;
    private OnTranslatePositionListener mOnTranslatePositionListener;

    // CropView Components
    private Matrix mMatrix;

    // MediaPlayer Attributes
    protected Uri mUri;
    private int mCurrentBufferPercentage;
    private int mSeekWhenPrepared;
    protected int mVideoWidth;
    protected int mVideoHeight;

    // CropView Attributes
    private float mRatioWidth;
    private float mRatioHeight;
    private float mPositionX;
    private float mPositionY;
    private float mBoundX;
    private float mBoundY;
    private int mRotate;
    private float mScaleX;
    private float mScaleY;
    private float mScale;

    // Working Variables
    private int mCurrentState = STATE_IDLE;
    private int mTargetState = STATE_IDLE;

    // Touch Event
    // past position x, y and move point
    float mPastX;
    float mPastY;
    float mTouchDistance;
    private Context context;

    // Constructors
    public VideoCropView(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;

        initAttributes();
        initVideoView();
    }

    public VideoCropView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;

        initAttributes(context, attrs, 0);
        initVideoView();
    }

    public VideoCropView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mContext = context;

        initAttributes(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initVideoView();
    }

    private void initAttributes() {
        mRatioWidth = 1;
        mRatioHeight = 1;
    }

    private void initAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.VideoCropView, defStyleAttr, 0);

        mRatioWidth = typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.VideoCropView_ratio_width, 3);
        mRatioHeight = typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.VideoCropView_ratio_height, 4);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightLayout;
        int widthLayout;
        widthLayout = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        heightLayout = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(widthLayout, heightLayout);

        /*if(widthMeasureSpec < heightMeasureSpec){

            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = (int) ((width / mRatioWidth) * mRatioHeight);


            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        }else{

            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height =MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        }
*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(mCurrentState == STATE_ERROR || mCurrentState == STATE_IDLE || mCurrentState == STATE_PREPARING) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mPastX = event.getX();
                mPastY = event.getY();
                mTouchDistance = 0;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(mBoundX!=0 || mBoundY!=0) {
                    float dx = event.getX() - mPastX;
                    float dy = event.getY() - mPastY;
                    updateViewPosition(dx, dy);
                    mPastX = event.getX();
                    mPastY = event.getY();
                    mTouchDistance += (Math.abs(dx) + Math.abs(dy));
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (mTouchDistance < 25) {
                    if (isPlaying()) {
                        pause();
                    } else {
                        start();
                    }
                }

                mTouchDistance = 0;
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(event);
        event.setClassName(VideoView.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info);
        info.setClassName(VideoView.class.getName());
    }

    public int resolveAdjustedSize(int desiredSize, int measureSpec) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Resolve called.");
        int result = desiredSize;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        switch (specMode) {
            case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
            /*
             * Parent says we can be as big as we want. Just don't be larger
             * than max size imposed on ourselves.
             */
                result = desiredSize;
                break;

            case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            /*
             * Parent says we can be as big as we want, up to specSize. Don't be
             * larger than specSize, and don't be larger than the max size
             * imposed on ourselves.
             */
                result = Math.min(desiredSize, specSize);
                break;

            case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                // No choice. Do what we are told.
                result = specSize;
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void initVideoView() {

        mVideoHeight = 0;
        mVideoWidth = 0;
        setFocusable(false);
        setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        mCurrentState = STATE_IDLE;
        mTargetState = STATE_IDLE;

    }

    public void setVideoPath(String path) {
        if (path != null) {
            setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        }
    }

    public void setVideoURI(Uri pVideoURI) {
        mUri = pVideoURI;
        mSeekWhenPrepared = 0;

        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(mContext, pVideoURI);

        // create thumbnail bitmap
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            String rotation = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION);

            try {
                mRotate = Integer.parseInt(rotation);
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                mRotate = 0;
            }
        }

        retriever.release();

        openVideo();
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void stopPlayback() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
            mCurrentState = STATE_IDLE;
            mTargetState = STATE_IDLE;
        }
    }

    public void openVideo() {
        if ((mUri == null) || (mSurface == null)) {
            // not ready for playback just yet, will try again later
            return;
        }
        // Tell the music playback service to pause
        // TODO: these constants need to be published somewhere in the
        // framework.
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
        intent.putExtra("command", "pause");
        mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);

        // we shouldn't clear the target state, because somebody might have
        // called start() previously
        release(false);
        try {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            // TODO: create SubtitleController in MediaPlayer, but we need
            // a context for the subtitle renderers

            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mPreparedListener);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(mSizeChangedListener);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(mErrorListener);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(mInfoListener);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(mBufferingUpdateListener);
            mCurrentBufferPercentage = 0;
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mContext, mUri);
            mMediaPlayer.setSurface(mSurface);
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mCurrentState = STATE_PREPARING;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            mCurrentState = STATE_ERROR;
            mTargetState = STATE_ERROR;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mCurrentState = STATE_ERROR;
            mTargetState = STATE_ERROR;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private OnVideoSizeChangedListener mSizeChangedListener = new OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVideoSizeChanged(final MediaPlayer mp, final int width,
                                       final int height) {
            mVideoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
            mVideoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();

            if (mVideoWidth != 0 && mVideoHeight != 0) {
                requestLayout();
                if(mVideoWidth >= mVideoHeight)
                initVideo();
            }
        }
    };

    private OnPreparedListener mPreparedListener = new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
            mCurrentState = STATE_PREPARED;

            if (mOnPreparedListener != null) {
                mOnPreparedListener.onPrepared(mp);
            }

            mVideoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
            mVideoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();

            int seekToPosition = mSeekWhenPrepared; // mSeekWhenPrepared may be
            // changed after seekTo()
            if (seekToPosition != 0) {
                seekTo(seekToPosition);
            }

            if ((mVideoWidth != 0) && (mVideoHeight != 0)) {
                if(mVideoWidth >= mVideoHeight) initVideo();

                if (mTargetState == STATE_PLAYING) {
                    start();
                }
            } else {
                // We don't know the video size yet, but should start anyway.
                // The video size might be reported to us later.
                if (mTargetState == STATE_PLAYING) {
                    start();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mp) {
            mCurrentState = STATE_PLAYBACK_COMPLETED;
            mTargetState = STATE_PLAYBACK_COMPLETED;

            if (mOCompletionListener != null) {
                mOCompletionListener.onCompletion(mMediaPlayer);
            }
        }
    };

    private OnInfoListener mInfoListener = new OnInfoListener() {
        public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int arg1, int arg2) {
            if (mOnInfoListener != null) {
                mOnInfoListener.onInfo(mp, arg1, arg2);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    private OnErrorListener mErrorListener = new OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int framework_err, int impl_err) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error: " + framework_err + "," + impl_err);
            mCurrentState = STATE_ERROR;
            mTargetState = STATE_ERROR;

            /* If an error handler has been supplied, use it and finish. */
            if (mOnErrorListener != null) {
                if (mOnErrorListener.onError(mMediaPlayer, framework_err,
                        impl_err)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    private OnBufferingUpdateListener mBufferingUpdateListener = new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBufferingUpdate(final MediaPlayer mp, final int percent) {
            mCurrentBufferPercentage = percent;
        }
    };

    public void setOnPreparedListener(OnPreparedListener listener) {
        mOnPreparedListener = listener;
    }

    public void setOnCompletionListener(OnCompletionListener listener) {
        mOCompletionListener = listener;
    }

    public void setOnErrorListener(OnErrorListener listener) {
        mOnErrorListener = listener;
    }

    public void setOnInfoListener(OnInfoListener listener) {
        mOnInfoListener = listener;
    }

    private void release(boolean cleartargetstate) {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
            mCurrentState = STATE_IDLE;
            if (cleartargetstate) {
                mTargetState = STATE_IDLE;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        if (isInPlaybackState()) {
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            mCurrentState = STATE_PLAYING;

        }
        mTargetState = STATE_PLAYING;
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        if (isInPlaybackState()) {
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mMediaPlayer.pause();
                mCurrentState = STATE_PAUSED;
            }
        }

        mTargetState = STATE_PAUSED;
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        if (isInPlaybackState()) {
            return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
        }

        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        if (isInPlaybackState()) {
            return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void seekTo(int msec) {
        if (isInPlaybackState()) {
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(msec);
            mSeekWhenPrepared = 0;
        } else {
            mSeekWhenPrepared = msec;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return isInPlaybackState() && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    @Override
    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            return mCurrentBufferPercentage;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private boolean isInPlaybackState() {
        return (mMediaPlayer != null && mCurrentState != STATE_ERROR
                && mCurrentState != STATE_IDLE && mCurrentState != STATE_PREPARING);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canPause() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAudioSessionId() {
        return -1;
    }

    SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            mSurface = new Surface(surface);
            openVideo();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            boolean isValidState = (mTargetState == STATE_PLAYING);
            boolean hasValidSize = (mVideoWidth == width && mVideoHeight == height);
            if (mMediaPlayer != null && isValidState && hasValidSize) {
                start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                mMediaPlayer.reset();
                mMediaPlayer.release();
                mMediaPlayer = null;
            }

            if (mSurface != null) {
                mSurface.release();
                mSurface = null;
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(final SurfaceTexture surface) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onVisibilityChanged(View changedView, int visibility) {
        super.onVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);

        if (visibility == View.INVISIBLE || visibility == View.GONE) {
            if (isPlaying()) {
                stopPlayback();
            }
        }
    }

    public float getScale() {
        return mScale;
    }

    private void initVideo() {
        try {
                int width = getWidth();
                int height = getHeight();
                mScaleX = 1.0f;
                mScaleY = 1.0f;
                mPositionX = 0;
                mPositionY = 0;
                mBoundX = 0;
                mBoundY = 0;
                mMatrix = new Matrix();

                mScaleX = (float) mVideoWidth / width;
                mScaleY = (float) mVideoHeight / height;

                mBoundX = width - mVideoWidth / mScaleY;
                mBoundY = height - mVideoHeight / mScaleX;

                if (mScaleX < mScaleY) {
                    mScale = mScaleX;
                    mScaleY = mScaleY * (1.0f / mScaleX);
                    mScaleX = 1.0f;
                    mBoundX = 0;
                } else {
                    mScale = mScaleY;
                    mScaleX = mScaleX * (1.0f / mScaleY);
                    mScaleY = 1.0f;
                    mBoundY = 0;
                }

                mMatrix = new Matrix();
                mMatrix.setScale(mScaleX, mScaleY);
                setTransform(mMatrix);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateViewPosition(float x, float y) {

        float nextX = mPositionX + x;
        float nextY = mPositionY + y;

        if(mScaleX == 1.0f) {
            x = 0;
        } else {
            if(nextX > 0) {
                x = -mPositionX;
                mPositionX = mPositionX + x;
            } else if(nextX < mBoundX) {
                x = mBoundX - mPositionX;
                mPositionX = mPositionX + x;
            } else {
                mPositionX = nextX;
            }
        }

        if(mScaleY == 1.0f) {
            y = 0;
        } else {
            if(nextY > 0) {
                y = -mPositionY;
                mPositionY = mPositionY + y;
            } else if(nextY < mBoundY) {
                y = mBoundY - mPositionY;
                mPositionY = mPositionY + y;
            } else {
                mPositionY = nextY;
            }
        }

        if(mOnTranslatePositionListener != null) {
            mOnTranslatePositionListener.onTranslatePosition(mPositionX, mPositionY, mPositionX * -mScale, mPositionY * -mScale);
        }

        mMatrix.postTranslate(x, y);
        setTransform(mMatrix);
        invalidate();
    }

//  public void setOriginalRatio() {
//      if(mVideoWidth != 0 && mVideoHeight != 0) {
//          int gcd = gcd(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
//          setRatio(mVideoWidth / gcd, mVideoHeight / gcd);
//      }
//  }

    public int gcd(int n, int m) {
        while (m != 0) {
            int t = n % m;
            n = m;
            m = t;
        }

        return Math.abs(n);
    }

//  public void setRatio(float ratioWidth, float ratioHeight) {
//      mRatioWidth = ratioWidth;
//      mRatioHeight = ratioHeight;
//
//      int seek = getCurrentPosition();
//
//      requestLayout();
//      invalidate();
//      openVideo();
//
//      seekTo(seek);
//  }


    public float getRatioWidth() {
        return mRatioWidth;
    }

    public float getRatioHeight() {
        return mRatioHeight;
    }

    public float getRealPositionX() {
        return mPositionX * -mScale;
    }

    public float getRealPositionY() {
        return mPositionY * -mScale;
    }

    public int getVideoWidth() {
        return mVideoWidth;
    }

    public int getVideoHeight() {
        return mVideoHeight;
    }

    public int getRotate() {
        return mRotate;
    }

    public void setOnTranslatePositionListener(OnTranslatePositionListener pOnTranslatePositionListener) {
        mOnTranslatePositionListener = pOnTranslatePositionListener;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public interface OnTranslatePositionListener {
        public abstract void onTranslatePosition(float x, float y, float rx, float ry);
    }
}
```

FFMPEG for cropping particular portion

> ffmpeg -i /sdcard/videokit/in.mp4 -filter:v crop=720:1088:0:0 -c:a copy /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4

```
public class SimpleExample extends Activity {

    String workFolder = null;
    String demoVideoFolder = null;
    String demoVideoPath = null;
    String vkLogPath = null;
    private boolean commandValidationFailedFlag = false;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ffmpeg_demo_client_1);

        demoVideoFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/videokit/";
        demoVideoPath = demoVideoFolder + "in.mp4";

        Log.i(Prefs.TAG, getString(R.string.app_name) + " version: " + GeneralUtils.getVersionName(getApplicationContext()) );
        workFolder = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
        //Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "workFolder: " + workFolder);
        vkLogPath = workFolder + "vk.log";

        GeneralUtils.copyLicenseFromAssetsToSDIfNeeded(this, workFolder);
        GeneralUtils.copyDemoVideoFromAssetsToSDIfNeeded(this, demoVideoFolder);

        Button invoke =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.invokeButton);
        invoke.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "run clicked.");
                if (GeneralUtils.checkIfFileExistAndNotEmpty(demoVideoPath)) {
                    new TranscdingBackground(SimpleExample.this).execute();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), demoVideoPath + " not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        int rc = GeneralUtils.isLicenseValid(getApplicationContext(), workFolder);
        Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "License check RC: " + rc);
    }

    public class TranscdingBackground extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer>
    {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        Activity _act;
        String commandStr;

        public TranscdingBackground (Activity act) {
            _act = act;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            EditText commandText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.CommandText);
            commandStr = commandText.getText().toString();

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(_act);
            progressDialog.setMessage("FFmpeg4Android Transcoding in progress...");
            progressDialog.show();

        }

        protected Integer doInBackground(String... paths) {
            Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "doInBackground started...");

            // delete previous log
            boolean isDeleted = GeneralUtils.deleteFileUtil(workFolder + "/vk.log");
            Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "vk deleted: " + isDeleted);

            PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)_act.getSystemService(Activity.POWER_SERVICE);
            WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "VK_LOCK");
            Log.d(Prefs.TAG, "Acquire wake lock");
            wakeLock.acquire();

            ///////////// Set Command using code (overriding the UI EditText) /////
            //commandStr = "ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/in.mp4 -strict experimental -s 320x240 -r 30 -aspect 3:4 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 2097152 /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4";
            //String[] complexCommand = {"ffmpeg", "-y" ,"-i", "/sdcard/videokit/in.mp4","-strict","experimental","-s", "160x120","-r","25", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b", "150k", "-ab","48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "/sdcard/videokit/out.mp4"};
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            LoadJNI vk = new LoadJNI();
            try {


                vk.run(GeneralUtils.utilConvertToComplex(commandStr), workFolder, getApplicationContext());




                GeneralUtils.copyFileToFolder(vkLogPath, demoVideoFolder);


            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Log.e(Prefs.TAG, "vk run exeption.", e);
            }
            finally {
                if (wakeLock.isHeld())
                    wakeLock.release();
                else{
                    Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "Wake lock is already released, doing nothing");
                }
            }
            Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "doInBackground finished");
            return Integer.valueOf(0);
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "onCancelled");
            //progressDialog.dismiss();
            super.onCancelled();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "onPostExecute");
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // finished Toast
            String rc = null;
            if (commandValidationFailedFlag) {
                rc = "Command Vaidation Failed";
            }
            else {
                rc = GeneralUtils.getReturnCodeFromLog(vkLogPath);
            }
            final String status = rc;
            SimpleExample.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(SimpleExample.this, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (status.equals("Transcoding Status: Failed")) {
                        Toast.makeText(SimpleExample.this, "Check: " + vkLogPath + " for more information.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: I have added some additional details with pictures for your information

Comment: Can you setScaleType to your view?

Answer (score 1):

try to use `getBitmap`: [TextureView.getBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html#getBitmap(int,%20int)) for `VideoCropView`
it returns bitmap wanted resolution.

Then you can crop using [Bitmap.createBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))
like this

`resizedbitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0,0,yourwidth, yourheight);`

Comment: bitmap is used for image cropping.Can we crop the video using this resized bitmap ?

Comment: This method help to retrieve cyrrent (shown) bitmap. If you need 'several frames' this is not a good solution. It depends on your problem.

Comment: I dont understand difference between video and image crooping in your example. Please, make it clear

Comment: I want to crop the landscape video which is visible in layout .(For eg: If i am having a video width 1280 . I am using only portrait view ,when user selected the landscape video it will display with panning .User can swipe the video right and left.When user press the crop button i want to crop the video which is visible in that frame and the frame width will be like only 720)

Answer (score 0):

Use this library to crop video with visible portion
[Video Trimmer Library](https://github.com/knowledge4life/k4l-video-trimmer)

Comment: I am using this library already,this will be used for video time cropper and will not crop the visible portion of the video.